# Calculating $\displaystyle{\lim _{n\to\infty}}(\sqrt{2n^2 - 10n + 11}-\sqrt{2n^2+7n-8})$

Tags: limits

I tried solving it using limit arithmetic, but since both operands strive to infinity, it doesn't work. From some substitutions I've done, the answer to this seems to be close to negative six, but I have no idea how to calculate this expression to get to that. What can I do?

Comment: Of the top of my head, the answer is $\;-\cfrac {17}{2\sqrt2}\;$ ....but I could be wrong. Why do you think the answer is $\;-6\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I figured it would round down, and I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{2n^2 - 10n + 11}+\sqrt{2n^2+7n-8}$ and using the difference of two squares gives
$$\sqrt{2n^2 - 10n + 11}-\sqrt{2n^2+7n-8}
  =\frac{-17n+19}{\sqrt{2n^2 - 10n + 11}+\sqrt{2n^2+7n-8}}\ .$$
Can you finish it from here?

BTW I don't think the answer is $-6$.

Comment: Sure it is, because everybody knows $\sqrt{2} = \frac{17}{12}$.

Comment: @MarkFischler LOL

Comment: @David I tried, but I don't know how to handle the denominator now.

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $n$ and simplify, being careful with the algebra in the denominator.